# Error in processing `keyup` event

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am new to `meteor`, please anyone help me to solve the issue below.

Let me first be clear on what project I am working on.

I have a collection which stores user details so I want to edit user information. I am using `iron-router`, so that when I enter `user_id` in URL it displays me user details in textbox, so I can edit them.

And I am able to save edited user details when I click on "Edit" button, but I want to update details automatically, so I tried to use `keyup` event but it is not working.

I am getting the following error when I'm handling `keyup` event instead of `submit`:

> Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at Object.keyup .sub

Below is my js code:

```
Router.route('/temp1/:_id', function () {
  var pid = this.params._id;
  this.render('temp1', {
    data: function () {
      return Dbs.findOne({ user_id: pid });
      Router.go("/temp1", {}, { id: pid });
    }
  });
});

Template.temp1.events({
  'keyup .sub'(event)  {
    const target = event.target;
    const user_id1 = target.user_id.value;
    const add1 = target.add.value;   
    const cont1 = target.cont.value;
    const pth1 = target.pth.value;

    var p = Dbs.findOne({ user_id: Router.current().params._id });
    Dbs.update({ _id: p._id }, {
      $set: {
        user_id: user_id1,
        cont: cont1,
        add: add1,
        pth: pth1
      }
    });
    console.log(user_id1);
    alert(user_id1);
  }
});
```

Html code:

```
  <form class="sub">
    <input type="text" name="user_id" value="{{user_id}}"/>
    <input type="text" name="add" value="{{add}}"/>
    <input type="text" name="cont" value="{{cont}}"/>
    <input type="text" name="pth" value="{{pth}}" />

    <!--<center><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="waves-effect #607d8b grey btn"></center>-->
 </form>
```

Comment: Can you show us the html code with the element with the class "sub" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using `submit .sub` event — inside your handler the `event.target` is `form`, that's why constructs like `target.user_id.value` are working.

When you're using `keyup .sub` event — this `keyup` event is bubbling to the form from its `input` elements, thus `event.target` will point to that `input` which dispatched this event.

There are two ways to "fix" your issue:

1. Use `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`
2. Replace this line:

   `const target = event.target;`

   with this one:

   `const target = $(event.target).closest('form').get(0);`

   So your `target` variable will always point to `form` element.